# running scripts is disabled for firebase hosting in vscode terminal

Tags: firebase-hosting

firebase : File C:\Users\CHRISTIN UNION\AppData\Roaming\npm\firebase.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see
about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.

Answer (score 3):

Open windows PowerShell as a Administrator mode. Run this command:

```
set-executionpolicy remotesigned
```

Then, type y to yes to all. Hope this will work.

Comment: Did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Open windows PowerShell as an Administrator mode. Run this command:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Then, type Y and hit the Enter button. It will work.